# In Rails, using Ransack Gem, how can I pass my search criteria to the sort_link helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, ransack

I'm trying to add my search criteria to my `sort_link` method that's provided by the [Ransack](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack) gem. Below is a an example of what I get when debugging the application.

```
(byebug) ransack_search_object
Ransack::Search<class: Player, base: Grouping <conditions: [Condition <attributes: ["position_id"], predicate: in, values: ["", "5"]>, Condition <attributes: ["measurable_summary_height"], predicate: gteq, values: ["6060"]>], combinator: and>>

(byebug) sort_link(ransack_search_object, "Pos", %i(position_abbreviation), { controller: "players", action: "ransack_search" })
"<a class=\"sort_link \" href=\"/players/ransack_search?q%5Bs%5D=position_abbreviation+asc\">Pos</a>"
```

As you can see above the search criteria is specified in `ransack_search_object`, but it doesn't appear in the `href` link that is generated.  I'm not sure why this is the case though.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, but have you tried removing `{ controller: "players", action: "ransack_search" }` from the `sort_link` options? My guess is you may be clobbering the existing search params.

Comment: @DerekHopper, thanks! Yes, I originally tried that, but since the action is different than the page it's on then I went with this code.  The code you mention would give me the following error...

`(byebug) sort_link(ransack_search_object, "Pos")
*** ActionController::UrlGenerationError Exception: No route matches {:q=>{"s"=>"Pos asc"}}`